# reason of this error in Cplex which appeared at the end of the code ;unexpected end of file found in comment

Tags: optimization, cplex

what is the reason of this error in Cplex which appeared at the end of the code ? unexpected end of file found in comment. I searched a lot but i could not find it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The model

```
// This model gives an error unexpected end of file in comment

/*
```

gives the same error. I guess you forgot to end a comment section with "*/"